# Hive regex serde for multi level YAML data?

Tags: regex, unix, hive

I have a custom export of several tables and their columns in multilevel yaml format. 
example extract modified with dummy values:

```
schemas:
- name: exports
  tables:
  - name: sugar
    description: makes stuff sweet
    active_date: 2019-01-07 00:00:00
    columns:
    - name: color
      type: abcd
    - name: taste
      type: abcd
      description: xyz
      example: 21352352
    - name: structure
      type: abcd
      description: xyzasaa
      example: 10001
  - name: salt
    description: not that sweet.
      makes it salty.
    active_date: 2018-12-18 00:00:00
    columns:
    - name: strength
      type: abcdef
      description: easy to find
      example: 2018-03-03 12:30:00
    - name: color
      type: abcdeffa
      description: not sweet
      example: 21352352
    - name: quality
      type: abcd
      description: how much is needed
      example: 10001
```

I need to ingest this data in hive table using some serde. I am familiar with jsonSerde but unfortunately this format is not supported and so looking for an alternate way. Can someone suggest an optimum approach? Can a regexSerde help at all with what I am trying to achieve?

Hive table Data can be represented maybe in one of the below ways:

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Level 1(name)</th><th>Level 2(name)</th><th>Level 2 (type)</th><th>Level 2 (description)</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>sugar</td><td>color</td><td>abcd</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>sugar</td><td>taste</td><td>abcd</td><td>xyz</td></tr>
 <tr><td>sugar</td><td>structure</td><td>abcd</td><td>xyzasaa</td></tr>
 <tr><td>salt</td><td>strength</td><td>abcdef</td><td>easy to find</td></tr>
 <tr><td>salt</td><td>color</td><td>abcdeffa</td><td>not sweet</td></tr>
 <tr><td>salt</td><td>quality</td><td>abcd</td><td>how much is needed</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

--- or ---

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Level 1(name.colum)</th><th>Level 2 (type)</th><th>Level 2 (description)</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>sugar.color</td><td>abcd</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>sugar.taste</td><td>abcd</td><td>xyz</td></tr>
 <tr><td>sugar.structure</td><td>abcd</td><td>xyzasaa</td></tr>
 <tr><td>salt.strength</td><td>abcdef</td><td>easy to find</td></tr>
 <tr><td>salt.color</td><td>abcdeffa</td><td>not sweet</td></tr>
 <tr><td>salt.quality</td><td>abcd</td><td>how much is needed</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

EDIT: Using simplest approach I was able to extract below:

```
$ grep -P '(?<=- name: ).*' export.yaml
- name: exports
  - name: sugar
    - name: color
    - name: taste
    - name: structure
  - name: salt
    - name: strength
    - name: color
    - name: quality
```

but how do I establish the indentation relationship so that result is like :

```
sugar.color,sugar.taste,sugar.structure
salt.strength,salt.color,salt.quality
```

Comment: if you can convert yaml to `json` you can then use json serde

Comment: As I said, json serde is an option and that will be final direction.  For now looking for regex gurus if it is at all possible to generate perhaps a csv similar to below hive table